# How to use Ordance Survey vector tiles with React-Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, vector-tiles, mapbox-api-vectortiles

I'm unsure of the correct syntax to add Ordnance Survey vector tiles to a React-Leaflet application.

The example code at https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-vector-tile-api/vts-3857-basic-map loads some vector tile libraries from Mapbox:

```
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mapbox-gl-leaflet/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js"></script>
```

then uses this JavaScript syntax to load the OS vector tiles:

```
// Load and display vector tile layer on the map.
var gl = L.mapboxGL({
    style: 'https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts/resources/styles?key=' + apiKey,
    transformRequest: url => {
        return {
            url: url += '&srs=3857'
        }
    }
});
```

(I've verified that my OS api key works in the stand-alone demo.)

How can accomplish the equivalent using React and Leaflet?

I'm using [React-Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) to add Leaflet functionality to my React app, and I've tried adding [react-leaflet-vector-tile-layer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-vector-tile-layer) - I've verified that this works for vector tile layers supplied by Mapbox Studio:

```
<VectorTileLayer
  styleUrl="mapbox://styles/my-org/my-style"
  accessToken="my-key"
/>
```

I'm trying to use this approach for the Ordnance Survey vector tile layer too but it's not working as I probably have the syntax wrong:

```
<VectorTileLayer
  styleUrl="https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts/resources/styles?key=my-key"
/>
```

No error message is shown but the OS vector tile layer does not appear on the map. In the developer console I can see a PBF file has been downloaded but it doesn't draw on the map. Could this be because I'm missing the `transformRequest` function in their example? Assuming it's required, how can I add this transformation request when using `react-leaflet-vector-tile-layer`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from Ted Piotrowski, the developer of the react-leaflet-vector-tile-layer library. I needed to add the `transformRequest` parameter using this syntax:

```
<VectorTileLayer
  styleUrl="https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts/resources/styles?key=my-key"
  transformRequest={url => { return { url: url += '&srs=3857' }}}
/>
```

Comment: `transformRequest' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & VectorTileLayerProps & RefAttributes<TileLayer>`