# Is there a way to render vector tiles on a React-Leaflet based map?

Tags: gis, react-leaflet, vector-tiles

I have an interactive map built with react-leaflet on which I want to render two vector tile layers, one of them renders points and the other renders polygons. The tiles are served by my own backend under the zoom, x, y coordinates system (zxy) and my URL is something similar to [https://example.com/.../tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}](https://example.com/.../tiles/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D)

The problem is I have not been able to render the layers at all.

My knowledge on React and leaflet is very limited, so the only thing I tried so far is to use a standard TileLayer:

```
<TileLayer
    attribution='me'
    url="http://localhost:8000/api/v3/polygon-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}"
    maxZoom={20}
    minZoom={15}
/>
```

As far as my understanding goes, this doesn't work because the TileLayer component only works when rendering image based tiles, not vectors.

Comment: Looks like you will need to create your own implementation or use a plugin for it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822077/how-to-use-ordance-survey-vector-tiles-with-react-leaflet